# Regex for AlphaNumeric words with special characters

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to make regex for capturing alphanumeric words with special characters.
The search will be done on small string of 4 - 5 words max and should extract a word.
The target string can be anywhere in the string but will be separated with spaces.

Eg:

```
"Bill No: THRD/20-21/110"
"CRN No: GSTASP/20-21/066"
"Identifier value: PCPL-2021-000152"
```

Need to get these values

```
THRD/20-21/110
GSTASP/20-21/066
PCPL-2021-000152
```

The special characters are limited to "/ -"
.So far all my approaches have Failed

Comment: I your target string always at the end?

Comment: @dawg no Target string can be anywhere in the string but is always separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to qualify that next non-space substring has either `/` or `-` in it:

```
(?<=[ \t])(?=[^ \t]*[/-])([0-9a-zA-Z/-]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eko9E9/1/)

That only works for a substring following a `[ \t]` taking literally your statement *Target string can be anywhere in the string but is always separated by spaces.*

---

If you want to capture potentially at the start of the string, remove the lookbehind:

```
(?=[^ \t]*[/-])([0-9a-zA-Z/-]+)
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/VDNtSo/1/)

That will capture any substring with that defined character set that has at least one `[/-]` in it (at the cost of the efficiency of using a `[ \t]` delimiter as an anchor...)

Note: If you use `-` as a literal character in a character class it either needs to be escaped or at the end of the class. Otherwise, the `-` defines a range in the character class. This is a sneaky bug that has bitten many with a regex trying to capture a literal `-`.

Comment: This Solution works well. However it also matches something like this
`Invoice/Note` in a string on my problem. Notice that my target string will always be alphanumeric i.e.. combination of both. I can solve this with simple python string methods. If you do have a elegant solution to this aswell it would be really appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Add a second lookahead that qualifies there is a digit in there: `(?=[^ \t]*[/-])(?=[^ \t]*[0-9])([0-9a-zA-Z/-]+)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y3dEbE/1)